# How to link layout pages to views MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a layout page (or master page) with MVC 3 and would like to make my views sort of content pages to this layout page, but alas I have no clue how to do this

I am totally new to MVC 3 and this may sound as a stupid question but I can't find anything relating to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view code, you would simply set the layout file.  Assuming your Layout is named `_Layout.cshtml` and stored in `/Views/Shared`, the code might be:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in MVC 3 we can set the layout page for the current view by doing this one

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home page";
    Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

if application need the same layout everywhere in application you can set them for whole application by making a `_ViewStart.cshtml` in views folder and place this one.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}
```

first code can be apply in the views for setting the layout for page only you have. or second can be apply in **_ViewStart.cshtml** in Views directories of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Also, when you create new view you can select a "master page" for it. By default it's whatever "_ViewStart.cshtml" is linking to.